# Connect two circles with a line (with DOM elements)

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, geometry, famo.us

I am struggling with connecting two circles with a line. I am using the [famo.us](http://famo.us/) library.

## [**DEMO** on Codepen](http://codepen.io/alp82/pen/xbrXRW)

a.k.a. "Two balls, one line."

---

## The Problem

Angle and length of the line are correct, but **the position is wrong**.

---

## First attempt

The important part should be **lines 114-116**:

```
connection.origin = [.5, .5];
connection.align = [.5, .5];
connection.body.setPosition([
    Math.min(sourcePos.x, targetPos.x),
    Math.min(sourcePos.y, targetPos.y)
]);
```

Appearently i am doing something wrong with the math. Playing around with those values gives me all kinds of results, but nothing is close to correct.

---

## Intended solution

(1) The minimal solution would be to connect the centres of the circles with the line.

(2) The better solution would be a line that is only touching the surface of both circles instead of going to the center.

(3) The ideal solution would have arrows on each end of the line to look like a directed graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixes it :

```js
connection.body.setPosition([
    sourcePos.x * Math.cos(angle) + sourcePos.y * Math.sin(angle),
    sourcePos.x * Math.sin(-angle)+ sourcePos.y * Math.cos(angle)
]);
```

- Your segment is defined by its extrimity in `source`and the angle and distance to `target`, thus you have to set its origin to be that of `source`
- The rotation seems to not only rotate the object, but also rotate the coordinates around the origin, so I rotated them by `-angle` to compensate.

There might be a more `famo.us`esque way to do it (maybe you can get it to rotate before setting the position, or have the position be 0,0 and add the coordinates as a translation in the transformation).

---

To get your better solution, still with mostly math, you may keep the same code but

- with `r` the radius of the `source` ball, remove `[r * distX / distance, r * distY / distance]` to the coordinates of the segment, to put it in contact with the outer part of the ball
- remove both balls' radius from the distance

With that, we get :

```js
var distX = sourcePos.x - targetPos.x;
var distY = sourcePos.y - targetPos.y;
var norm = Math.sqrt(distX * distX + distY * distY);
var distance = norm - (source.size[0]+target.size[0])/2;
var angle = -Math.atan2(-distY, distX);
connection.angle = angle;
connection.size = [distance, 2, 0];
connection.align = [.5, .5];
connection.origin = [.5, .5];
var posX = sourcePos.x - source.size[0]/2 * (distX / norm);
var posY = sourcePos.y - source.size[0]/2 * (distY / norm);
connection.body.setPosition([
  posX * Math.cos(angle) + posY * Math.sin(angle),
  posX * Math.sin(-angle)+ posY * Math.cos(angle)
]);
```

result on this fork : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEjPLg

I think the fact that the line length is off when the balls go fast is a timing issue. Most probably you compute the segment's length and position at a moment when the ball's centres are not yet updated for that frame.

Comment: Your point with being one step behind the render cycle seems to be true. Nevertheless, your explanations helped me alot. Thank you!

Comment: For fixing the render step issue just replace `prerender` with `postrender`